# using Application.Caller in Excel text function (Text.BetweenDelimiters)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using a programatically made VBA buttons in my Excel sheet, and use Application.Caller as a way to send some parameters to the sub calling by this button. Now I'm trying to extract these parameters thanks to this Sub

here is my test (work perfectly & the string is actually the same as Application.Caller content) :

```
Public Sub DB_Export_Click() ' assign an action to the DB button
Dim ke, Li, item1, item2 As Integer

item1 = InStr("Export (23-25)", "(") ' position of start delimiter
item2 = InStr("Export (23-25)", "-") ' position of end delimiter
ke = CInt(Mid("Export (23-25)", item1 + 1, item2 - item1 - 1)) ' extract the string between two delimiters and convert it to integer
MsgBox (ke)

item1 = InStr("Export (23-25)", "-") ' position of start delimiter
item2 = InStr("Export (23-25)", ")") ' position of end delimiter
Li = CInt(Mid("Export (23-25)", item1 + 1, item2 - item1 - 1)) ' extract the string between two delimiters and convert it to integer
MsgBox (Li)
```

Here the real code (invalide procedur call or argument) :

```
Public Sub DB_Export_Click() ' assign an action to the DB button
Dim ke, Li, item1, item2 As Integer

item1 = InStr(CStr(Application.Caller), "(") ' position of start delimiter
item2 = InStr(CStr(Application.Caller), "-") ' position of end delimiter
ke = CInt(Mid(CStr(Application.Caller), item1 + 1, item2 - item1 - 1)) ' extract the string between two delimiters and convert it to integer
MsgBox (ke)

item1 = InStr(CStr(Application.Caller), "-") ' position of start delimiter
item2 = InStr(CStr(Application.Caller), ")") ' position of end delimiter
Li = CInt(Mid(CStr(Application.Caller), item1 + 1, item2 - item1 - 1)) ' extract the string between two delimiters and convert it to integer
MsgBox (Li)

'Re_Edit_Form K:=ke, Line:=Li
 End Sub
```

So all I need is to find a way to use Application.caller as a string.
Any Help ?

Comment: Damnnn that's right ... I'm using both so I made few mistakes, thanks. I will edit my post because I'm still stuck event after corrected that

Comment: Perhaps `ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller).Caption`?

Comment: `Application.Caller` will be an object of type `Shape` (for example, depending on exactly what a "VBA button" is), so as @BigBen notes you need to start from that idea.

Comment: What type of 'buttons' are you creating? ActiveX or Forms?

Comment: I'm using a ActiveX button, I'm trying to use @BigBen methode, thanks to him I can show the name of my button but for some reason I can't use CInt function on it. Maybe I made another mistake, I'm still on it

Comment: All good it work well thanks to @BigBen, the answer was to use ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller).Name insted of ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller).Caption